# What happens if the aggregator of a KGroupedStream returns null?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
KStream<Integer, Integer> stream;
KGroupedStream<Integer, Integer> grouped = stream.groupByKey();
KTable<Integer, Integer> aggregated = grouped.aggregate(
    () -> 0,
    (k, i, agg) -> {
       if (agg == null)
         agg = 0;
       Integer sum = agg + i;
       return sum > 100 ? null : sum;
    });
```

The messages on my stream are:

1. (1, 50)
2. (1, 75)
3. (1, 50)

When the second message arrives the Aggregator returns null. Does `KTable aggregated` receive (1, null) and deletes its state for key=1?

When message#3 arrives is `agg` null or is the Initializer called again and sets `agg` to 0?

What if I use reduce instead of aggregate, if the Reducer returns null will the next message go through the Reducer or will it be used 'as is' like it was the first message in the group?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the second message arrives the Aggregator returns null. Does KTable aggregated receive (1, null) and deletes its state for key=1?

Yes.

> When message#3 arrives is agg null or is the Initializer called again and sets agg to 0?

Initializer is called again.

> What if I use reduce instead of aggregate, if the Reducer returns null will the next message go through the Reducer or will it be used 'as is' like it was the first message in the group?

Reduce works like aggregate. Thus, if you return `null`, the following message will be processed as if it was the first message.

Meta comment: why do you not just run the code and try it out???

Comment: Why not just run the code? The docs for `KGroupedTable` says 

> When a record key is received for the first time, the initializer is called (and called before the adder and subtractor). **Note that, in contrast to KGroupedStream, over time the initializer may be called more than once for a key as a result of having received input tombstone records for that key** (see below).

To me this suggests that the initializer is only ever called once for `KGroupedStream` so when I saw a different behavior I asked the question because I thought the result I was seeing may have been version dependent

Comment: Well -- you could still try it out to see what happens :) -- Anyway. I see your point about the docs. They are incomplete. Note though, the part you cite talks about _input_ records and they are handled differently for KStream and KTable. For KStream, _input_ records with `null` value will be dropped (your original question was not about input records but about the _output_ records of an aggregation, ie, "returns null"). For KTable, _input_ records with `null` value (ie, tombstones) are processed regularly as described in the docs. Does this make sense?

Comment: I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7492 -- feel free to pick it up and contribute :)

Comment: Maybe at some point I'll have a good enough grasp of the subject to start contributing... in the mean time ... with my message order the **output** will normally be (1,50), (1,null), (1,50).  But what about record caches? Is it possible that some of these get compacted? Along with the _normal_ sequence I can think of 3 additional potential output sequences a) (1,50) b) (1,null),(1,50) c) (1,50),(1,50). Are all these possible or is `null` special in some way and is guaranteed to always be sent downstream?

Comment: All sequences are possible. `null` is not special for caching.